# JavaScript to jQuery syntax Still need help on Converting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can not find out what is going wrong while running.
Here I'm trying to re-write JavaScript to jQuery syntax.
What exactly is incorrect? What I'm doing wrong.

Legacy >>

```
var cssmenuids = ["navmenu"];

    function createcssmenu()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < cssmenuids.length; i++)
             var ultags = document.getElementById(cssmenuids[i]).getElementsByTagName("ul");
            for (var t = 0; t < ultags.length; t++)
            {
                ultags[t].style.top = ultags[t].parentNode.offsetHeight + "-1px";
                ultags[t].parentNode.onmouseover = function()
                {
                    this.style.zIndex = 100;
                    this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
                    this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.zIndex = 0;
                }
                ultags[t].parentNode.onmouseout = function()
                {
                    this.style.zIndex = 0;
                    this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
                    this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.zIndex = 100;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (window.addEventListener)
        window.addEventListener("load", createcssmenu, false);
    else if (window.attachEvent)
        window.attachEvent("onload", createcssmenu);
```

jQuery Syntax >>

```
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('ul#navmenu').height = $('ul#navmenu').parent.height + "-1px";

        $('ul#navmenu').parent.bind('mouseover', function ()
        {
            $(this).css('z-index', 100);
            $(this).$('ul')[0].css("visibility", "visible");
            $(this).$('ul')[0].css('z-index', 0);
        });
        $('ul#navmenu').parent.bind('mouseout', function ()
        {
            $(this).css('z-index', 0);
            $(this).$('ul')[0].css("visibility", "hidden");
            $(this).$('ul')[0].css('z-index', 100);
        });
    });
```

That's it on JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sublay/HCajr/

Related question [JavaScript to jQuery syntax Building custom CSS horizontal menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035139/javascript-to-jquery-syntax-building-custom-css-horizontal-menu)

Comment: What happens? What errors do you get?

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML this code is running against? Including it all in a jsfiddle would help too. http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing parenthesis on most of your calls.

Declaring the height should look like this

```
$('ul#navmenu').height($('ul#navmenu').parent().height() -1)
```

You need to use `.parent()` not `.parent`

```
$('ul#navmenu').parent().bind('mouseover'
```

Below, it seem as if you are trying to first the first available `ul` within `#navmenu`. When you use `[0]` you're actually calling `.get()` which converts the jQuery object to a javascript DOM element. Doing that will remove the ability for you to run jQuery functions against it. Also, chaining doesn't happen like that for selectors. Also, `.css()` will accept an object with key:value pairs.

```
$(this).find('ul:first').css({
    "visibility" : "visible",
    "z-index" : 0
});
```

Once again, missing the `()` for `.parent()`

```
$('ul#navmenu').parent().bind('mouseout',
```

And again, the selector chain is wrong.

```
$(this).find('ul:first').css({
    "visibility" : "hidden",
    'z-index' : 100
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Height is a method, not a property.  You have to set it likewise:

```
$('ul#navmenu').height($('ul#navmenu').parent.height + "-1px");
```