# JavaScript to jQuery syntax Building custom CSS horizontal menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a horizontal menu using traditional JavaScript.

```
function createcssmenu()
{
    var ultags = document.getElementById("navmenu").getElementsByTagName("ul");
    for (var t = 0; t < ultags.length; t++)
    {
        ultags[t].style.top = ultags[t].parentNode.offsetHeight -1 + "px";
        ultags[t].parentNode.onmouseover = function()
        {
            this.style.zIndex = 100;
            this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
            this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.zIndex = 0;
        }
        ultags[t].parentNode.onmouseout = function()
        {
            this.style.zIndex = 0;
            this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
            this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.zIndex = 100;
        }
    }
}

if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", createcssmenu, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", createcssmenu);
```

I need to re-write it using jQuery syntax.

This is where I came to:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#navmenu ul').css('top', $('#navmenu ul').parent().height() - 1 + "px");

    $('#navmenu ul').parent().bind('mouseover', function ()
    {
        $(this).css('z-index', 100);
        $('#navmenu ul').css({ 'visibility': 'visible', 'z-index': 0 });
    });

    $('#navmenu ul').parent().bind('mouseout', function ()
    {
        $(this).css('z-index', 0);
        $('#navmenu ul').css({ 'visibility': 'hidden', 'z-index': 100 });
    });
});
```

It doesn't work correct.

I still have trouble with `this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0]` line.

Look at JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sublay/HCajr/

It should work a normal menu.

Thank you!

Related question [JavaScript to jQuery syntax Still need help on Converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16025815/javascript-to-jquery-syntax-still-need-help-on-converting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  think this is what you want [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh007/HCajr/17/)

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#navmenu ul').css('top', $('#navmenu ul').parent().height() - 1 + "px");
    $('#navmenu ul').each(function(){
        $(this).css('top', $(this).parent().height() - 1 + "px")
    });

    $('#navmenu ul').parent().bind('mouseover', function ()
    {
        $(this).css('z-index', 100);
        $('ul',this).css({ 'visibility': 'visible', 'z-index': 0 });
    });

    $('#navmenu ul').parent().bind('mouseout', function ()
    {
        $(this).css('z-index', 0);
         $('ul',this).css({ 'visibility': 'hidden', 'z-index': 100 });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to rewrite the above javascript, you could always just simplify it.

Have a look at this fiddle - **http://jsfiddle.net/DeHQ5/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#navmenu ul').css('top', $('#navmenu ul').parent().height() - 1 + "px");

    $('#navmenu > li').bind('mouseover', function () {
        $(this).children('ul').css({
            'visibility': 'visible',
            'z-index': 0
        });
    });

    $('#navmenu > li').bind('mouseout', function () {
        $(this).children('ul').css({
            'visibility': 'hidden',
            'z-index': 100
        });
    });
});
```

The main change is the initial sibling selector `#navmenu > li`.

Comment: As long you are using a version of jquery that is compatible with ie7 then they will be.